# Slick2d, independent monster movement

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm using slick2d to create a sort of open-world rogue like RPG. I'm wondering what method I could use to move and animate multiple monsters, in multiple rooms, while i'm walking around from room to room doing whatever. I have a method, but I feel it is EXTREMELY inefficient, and doesn't even work right. (involves a constant for loop, that handles monster movement x and y, and has trouble with animating at the same time)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks. I'm just asking for the method in words, but any snippets of code as pseudocode or little jiblets would be EXTREMLEY useful.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of monsters which are "active" -- near enough to potentially be visible, or active out of sight -- as distinct from "suspended" monsters further away in the world.

When the player crosses a "coarse grid" boundary (say every 64-128 pixels, or whatever), update the "active" list. Monsters which the player is now approaching will move onto the active list, monsters the player has left behind will move off the active list.

"Hibernating" monsters may potentially be stored as a map or multimap, by "coarse grid" location.

An algorithm like this will enable you to keep animation & monster calculation reasonable by limiting to monsters in the local area, while retaining monsters throughout a large world in a suspended state.

When the player actually sees the monster again, it should have had some opportunity to be active "out of sight", move, fight other monsters etc -- thus giving the appearance of having been active all the time.

To give monsters the most ability to "sneak around" and come up on players from behind, you can set the "active range" to be at least 2.5x the player's visibility distance, perhaps more. This, combined with range of pathfinding algorithms including sneaky (stay out of player's sight), can help make them genuinely challenging adversaries.